# Como fazer para quando for clicado um botão seja criado um elemento na página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso que quando uma pessoa clique em determinado botão, seja criado um elemento na página.

Vou explicar o que quero fazer com isso.

> Estou criando um botão, e quando é clicado, aparece um `modal-box` (uma espécie de janelinha que abaixa na tela), e dentro desse modal, quero colocar alguns widgets sociais, como facebook, twitter, Google+, etc... Porém preciso que esses widgets sejam carregados somente quando a pessoa clicar nesse botão "compartilhar".

O que preciso é isso.

Um link que ao ser clicado, seja carregado o conteúdo do modal.

**Meu código**

Botão:

```
<a href="#compartilhar" data-toggle="modal">Compartilhar</a>
```

Modal:

```
<div id="compartilhar" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <span id="loginModalLabel">Compartilhe!</span>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <!-- AQUI IRÁ FICAR O CONTEÚDO CARREGADO /-->
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Obrigado desde já :D

Comment: "preciso que esses widgets sejam carregados somente quando a pessoa clicar nesse botão" <- porquê? esse modal não está escondido? ou est+a a usar o `modal` para conteudos diferentes?

Comment: Exatamente, uso pra outras coisas também. Quero que seja carregado só quando clique porque carregado junto com a página pesa no carregamento. Obrigado por perguntar.

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias maneiras de se fazer isso. Se estiver usando jQuery pode usar métodos como [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/), [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/), [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), e por ai vai...

Aqui vai um exemplo de uso:

```js
// Conteúdo que deseja inserir
var oDiv = '<div class="modal">Conteúdo do modal</div>';

// Captura o evento de clique
$('a[href="#compartilhar"]').click(function(event) {

    // Previne que o link recarregue a página
 event.preventDefault();

    // Checa se a class modal existe
 if(!$('.modal').length) {
  
  // Se não existir, insere
  $(this).after(oDiv);
 }
 else {
  
  // Se existir da um fadeToggle();
  $('.modal').fadeToggle();
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#compartilhar" data-toggle="modal">Compartilhar</a>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem como funciona seu exemplo. No caso `var oDiv = '<div class="modal">Conteúdo do modal</div>';` será o conteúdo carregado?

Comment: Exatamente, ali você passa como string todo o conteúdo que deseja inserir no seu modal.

Comment: E onde o conteúdo vai aparecer? Ps: Não sou pro em jQuery. No caso tenho que criar uma `<div>` por exemplo, com a classe `.modal`? E ele irá aparecer nessa `<div>`?

Comment: No caso vou criar uma `<div>` com a classe `conteudo-div` e quero que ele apareça dentro dessa `<div>`.

Comment: Aqui está seu exemplo em um Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/291fo7sn/ caso queira fazer testes.

Comment: No caso o botão fica na página, e o conteúdo carregado fica dentro do modal. Ou seja, quando a pessoa clica, automaticamente abre o modal e carrega o conteúdo dentro.

Comment: Sim, exato. Basta que insira todo o HTML que deve aparecer no modal dentro da variável "oDiv". Veja o exemplo mais mais elementos: http://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/yyrs5so1.
Só não se esqueça que esse HTML deve estar todo em uma única linha... Pode usar algum minificador de HTML para fazer isso se precisar.

Comment: Irei testar :) parece que dá certo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar `.load()` para carregar uma outra página HTML dentro do modal, assim você separa o conteúdo da página e reutiliza em outras.

O exemplo a seguir é acionado quando for requisitado a abertura do modal:

```
$('#compartilhar').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Compartilhar')
    modal.find('.moda-body').load('compartilhar.html')
})
```

Comment: Interessante... Vou testar :)

Answer (score 0):

Existem dois jeitos de se fazer isso, o primeiro é pelo .append(), ae você pode colocar seu HTML dentro disso!

A segunda é pelo .html(), vc pode criar uma pagina HTML com esses widgets e dar um .html() na sua div passando sua pagina HTML como parametro.

Segue os links da documentação:
http://api.jquery.com/html/
http://api.jquery.com/append/