# Para performance HTML externo ou interno (Bootstrap-Modal)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou construindo uma pagina a qual será acessada por uma quantidade consideravel de usuarios (5 mil/dia) e como alguns servições de hospedagem cobram por massa de dados transferidos outros pela quantidade de requisições, isso me levantou uma questão: É melhor encapsular os Dados/Formularios de Cadastro/Login mais Requisitados em um Bootstrap-Modal e os de menor acesso em html externo a ser renderizado em outra url?

```
Qual das alternativas é melhor? 
Detalhes: Pagina de Login e Cadastro (muito acessada) ~3KB
Página de FAQ: (Pouco acessada) ~7KB
Página de TOS: (Pouco acessada) ~30KB
Página de Privacy Policy: (Pouco acessada) ~30KB
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem qual o seu problema.

Comment: Devido ao tamanho da pagina seria melhor colocar paginas como um modal (logo teria duas paginas dentro de uma) ou arquivos separados

Comment: Você pode carregar dentro do modal páginas externas usando `.load()`

Comment: Este carregamento seria quanto o usuario clica-se no botão que abre o modal? tipo ajax?

Comment: Sim, veja neste link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44636/como-fazer-para-quando-for-clicado-um-botão-seja-criado-um-elemento-na-página/44699#44699

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você for pagar por dados que são transferidos eu sugiro que você faça o seguinte:

- Empacotamento e minificação dos arquivos css
- Empacotamento e minificação dos arquivos js
- Evite css inline. use sempre em arquivo separado
- Utilize frameworks como o angular ou Backbone para carregamento de informações que são preenchidas na tela. Ex. Grids. Assim você só trafega json em vez de html que é muito mais pesado.
- utilize sprite css para imagens pois reduz o numero de requisições ao servidor. Eu também gosto de converter as imagens pequenas para base 64 e colocar direto no arquivo css mas isso é mais difícil de manter. Se você usa o visual studio para desenvolvimento pode instalar o webessentials que ajuda muito nisso, inclusive ele minifica arquivos css e js também.
- Otimize as imagens para sempre ficar no menor tamanho. Geralmente uso png mas nem sempre ele é melhor. Dê uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-when-best-to-use

Arquivos estáticos como .js, imagens, .css e .html são gravados no cache do navegador e não são tranferidos sempre. quando estão no cache o servidor retorna codigo http 304 (não modificado) isso também ajuda para uma menor transferência de dados.

Espero ter ajudado. Como não sei se você trabalha com que tecnologia você trabalha não poderei ajudar mais. Se for trabalhar com asp.net usando o iis como servidor veja como empacotar e minificar todos os arquivos css ou js em um só.